# Google Compute Engine -- Necessary to route through proxy to get to google services on private ip?

Tags: google-compute-engine

On GCE we plan on having a large number of worker compute VM instances (like 1000).  Each worker instance need to access Google Cloud buckets storage.  We don't have enough pubic IP address quota to give all of the compute nodes public IP addresses so they will have private IP addresses.  In tests, we found (and were surprised) that we couldn't access the Google Cloud bucket service from a private IP address.

We found a way to route packets from the private ip addresses through a proxy instance but we're afraid this isn't going to scale well.  One (or a few) proxies for 1000 workers? -- it sounds like it might not scale well and seems unnecessary.

Perhaps we just don't not understand something. Is there a way to make a instance with a private IP address access Google Cloud buckets without routing through a proxy instance?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access services outside your GCE network without a public IP. Your best bet is to apply to [increase your public IP address quota](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform?entry.1036535597&entry.1823281902&entry.1934621431&entry.612627929&entry.666100773&entry.2004330804&entry.1287827925&entry.1005864466&entry.511996332&entry.308842821&entry.1506342651&entry.1193238839=No&entry.1270586847&entry.394661533&entry.1276962733&entry.1256670372&entry.1742484064&entry.1553073272&entry.1438649533&entry.1545046927&entry.230434627&entry.961931604).

Answer (score 0):

May be you could start with setting up a Proxy per say 100 worker instances and see how your performance for Cloud Buckets access is. Is it ready-only vs. read-write ?